# Can I apply multiple Blasting Jellies to the same square?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

[Blasting Jelly](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/EquipmentMiscDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Blasting%20jelly) (relevant):

> This volatile gray paste sticks to solid surfaces and creates a concentrated blast when exposed to fire, making it a valuable excavation tool. You can apply 1 dose of blasting jelly to a 5-foot square as a standard action. The paste can be ignited with another standard action by striking it from an adjacent square with a metal weapon or object. When thus ignited or otherwise exposed to fire, the jelly explodes, dealing 2d6 points of fire damage to creatures and unattended objects within the treated square. If the ignited square is adjacent to another square containing blasting jelly, that square ignites as well.

The question is pretty straightforward: can I apply multiple doses of Blasting Jelly to the same 5' grid square? Assuming that's possible, would the damage stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The application rules state:

> You can apply 1 dose of blasting jelly to a 5-foot square as a standard action.

No further requirements are stated for application.  You may apply as many doses as you like.  As a piece of trivia, the maximum number of doses a single normal creature can apply to a single space at once is 2400 (at that point applications start becoming inert at the same rate new ones are added).

Comment: Although I agree these are the rules are written, I would as a GM rule that the damages do not stack it since it just feels wrong.

Comment: @AnneAunyme I think it would be better just to rule that you can't apply more than one dose to a square-- refusing to let the damage stack after allowing multiple applications without warning seems like it would be unfair to any players that had invested significant resources in such a plan.

Comment: Definitely, warning your players is important, otherwise it's unfair. Even with that houserule you could want to apply jelly to an already jellyfied square to "refresh" it (when it's close to its 4h lifetime), that's why I would better rule that the damages don't stack than that the jelly can't be stack-piled.